# SQL Oracle Query for counting number of orders per city

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called **"Orders"** and I need to get a list with only the name of the cities that have had more than 30 orders.

**the columns:**

```
OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, TerritoryID,
Orderdate, Requireddate, Shippeddate, Shipvia,
Freight, Shipname, Shipaddress, Shipcity, Shipregion,
Shippostalcode, Shipcountry
```

I have managed to get it to tell me the number of orders by city with the 'Shippostalcode' but I don't know how to tell it to show me only those with more than 30 orders

The code I was trying was this:

```
SELECT shipcity,
        COUNT(shippostalcode) AS order_numbers
        FROM orders
        where order_numbers>30
   GROUP BY shipcity
   ORDER BY order_numbers DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a `WHERE`, but `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT shipcity,
       COUNT(*) AS order_numbers
FROM orders
GROUP BY shipcity
HAVING COUNT(*) > 30
ORDER BY order_numbers DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you very much and if I only want you to show me the cities without the number of orders, how can I do it?

Comment: You can't, not with the ORDERS table only. You have to have yet another table that contains all cities. Then you'd e.g. `select shipcity from cities minus select shipcity from orders`.

Comment: In the end I left it this way where it only shows me the cities, I don't know if it's well done like this `SELECT shipcity as Ciudades
FROM orders
GROUP BY shipcity
HAVING COUNT(shipcity) > 30`

Comment: That's almost exactly the same as query I posted (you didn't display number of orders and didn't sort the result), so ... not really an improvement, in my opinion. And it certainly doesn't display cities without orders.

Comment: Sorry if I explained myself wrong, what I wanted was to hide the number of orders and only tell me the cities.

Of course the code is yours and I thank you very much, I am very new to oracle and I am trying to learn, some things are really difficult for me

Again I would like to thank you, I wish I could give you +1, but being new they do not allow me to vote on your answer

Comment: Oh, it seems I misunderstood what you were saying. OK, yes - omit COUNT function from SELECT column list (just as you posted in your comment an hour ago). You're welcome, I'm glad you made it!